# Message queueing messages over 4MB

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, message-queue, msmq, transactional-queue

I know that Message Queuing has a Message Size Limit of 4MB, but have recently run into situations where it will be necessary for me to support messages that are greater than 4MB. I have seen it mentioned that it is possible to use a transactional queue and split a message into 'chunks', then re-assemble them on the receiving end, but have seen very little information on how to accomplish this. The messages I am sending contain SQL record data formatted in XML (We use some Nvarchar(MAX) and varbinary(Max) fields, which is why the size limit is an issue. Any assistance in accomplishing this would be most appreciated!

Comment: Usually you would just send a pointer to the data in the message so the queue process can pull it out of a database or file or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSFT have documented a code sample here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198686

Comment: Thank you for the link - based on what I am seeing in this sample, it looks like a 'multipart message' is basically just several smaller messages with some sort of user-build/defined link between them which you use to re-assemble on the other end? For some reason I thought there might be a little more.. infrastructure on Microsoft's part for this sort of thing.